# Derivation of score vector

Tags: bayesian, survival, likelihood, frequentist, derivative

Can anyone explain the process of this derivation, step by step? This derivation is from Joint Models for Longitudinal and Time-to Event Data by Dimitris Rizopoulos.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
S(\theta) &= \sum_i \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\top}\log\int p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)db_i \\
&= \sum_i\frac{1}{p(T_i, \delta_i, y_i; \theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\top}\int  p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)db_i \\
& = \sum_i\frac{1}{p(T_i, \delta_i, y_i; \theta)}\int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\top}\{ p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)\}db_i \\
& =\sum_i\int\bigg[ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\top}\log\{ p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)\}\bigg]\\
& \times \frac{p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)}{p(T_i, \delta_i, y_i; \theta)}db_i \\
&=\sum_i\int A(\theta,b_i)p(b_i \mid T_i, \delta_i, y_i; \theta)db_i,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $A(\cdot)$ denotes the complete data score vector, given by $A(\theta,b_i) = \partial\{\log p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta) + \log p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta) + \log p(b_i;\theta)\}/\partial \theta^\top$.

I also do not understand using a posterior distribution for the random effects $b_i$, since this is a frequentist derivation. Bayesians would have no need to integrate over the random effects, since the random effects vector is considered a parameter in the Bayesian regime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First recall that $(\log f)' = \frac{f'}{f}$.

We have

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log\int p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)db_i = \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \int p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)db_i}{\int p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)db_i}
$$

Now$^*$, 
\begin{align*}
\int p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)db_i &= \int p(T_i,\delta_i,y_i \mid b_i ; \theta)p(b_i; \theta)db_i \\
&=  p(T_i,\delta_i,y_i; \theta)
\end{align*}
since we integrate the conditional probability it gives the marginal probability.

Under some regularity/integrability asumptions we have,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\int  p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)db_i  = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\{ p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)\}db_i.
$$

Since $(\log f)' = \frac{f'}{f} \Longrightarrow f'= f (\log f)'$

Thus we can rewrite, 
$$
\frac{1}{p(T_i, \delta_i, y_i; \theta)}\int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\{ p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)\}db_i \\
$$
as:
$$
\int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log \big( p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)\big) \times \frac{p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)}{p(T_i, \delta_i, y_i; \theta)} dbi_i
$$

From the Bayes formula we have$^*$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)}{p(T_i, \delta_i, y_i; \theta)}  &= \frac{p(T_i, \delta_i,y_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(b_i;\theta)}{p(T_i, \delta_i, y_i; \theta)} \\
&=p(b_i \mid T_i,\delta_i,y_i ; \theta)
\end{align*}
Thus finally if we note
$$
A(\theta,b_i) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log \big( p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)\big)
$$

We have,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^\top}\log\int p(T_i, \delta_i \mid b_i; \theta)p(y_i \mid b_i;\theta)p(b_i;\theta)db_i \\ = \int A(\theta,b_i) p(b_i \mid T_i,\delta_i,Y_i ; \theta) db_i
$$

Thus sums follows by taking this respect to each individual in the sample.

$^*$ here we use $(T, \delta) \perp Y \mid b$ which I think is common assumption in joint modeling

Comment: Perfect! Very easy to follow. And, yes! It is very common to assume that $(T,\delta) \perp Y \mid b$ when using joint models for longitudinal and time-to-event data.